# how update sqlite.net in android xamarin

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I have a db with one table, in table I have fields(id,name,place,course,homework,score)

```
public class LoginTable
{
   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_Id")]
   public int id { get; set; }

   public string name{ get; set; }
   public string place{ get; set; }
   public string course{ get; set; }

   public string homework{ get; set; }
   public string score{ get; set; }
```

Now I want to change values field (score) for all row in table with this term:

```
var data1 = data.Where(x => x.name == "a" && x.place == "b");
if (data1 != null)
{ HELP ME HERE !!!!" HOW CALL ALL ROW of Table(DB) HERE  AND CALCULATE SCORE (UPDATE FIELDS SCORE)" }
```

I don't know whats written in `if {}`!
Note: I want to calculate new score with this function: score+homework=(new)score

[image]

Comment: http://uupload.ir/files/xog7_capture.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sqlite use,

```
dbContext.InsertOrReplace(data)
or
dbContext.Update(data)
```

Update:

```
var data1 = data.Where(x => x.name == "a" && x.place == "b");
foreach(var item in data1)
{
     item.score = /*your value*/
     dbContext.Update(item);
}
```

Comment: please see http://uupload.ir/files/xog7_capture.jpg   .i want change score when   var data1 = data.Where(x => x.name == "a" && x.place == "b");
if (data1 != null){ whats write here}

Comment: Please mark as answer and upvote if you find it useful and help others to show the answer helped you.